# Can the Fujifilm X-H1 shoot video in AF-S mode?

Tags: fujifilm

I can't seem to get AF-S working on my new X-H1. If I change the switch on the front of the camera to S, it still shows AF-C while I'm shooting, and the menu system is no help.

Most of the info online has people either recommending to just use manual or AF-C, but I want to have the focusing system turned on so I can just do a quick focus and then start recording. When I do this with AF-C though, I get so so much hunting with my 16.mm f2.8 - it's actually pretty crazy how bad it is, never had a camera hunt this much in AF-C, almost wonder if something is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I got same issue!

You have to turn off auto face detection

Then af-s will be not changed to af-c in video

At least this is how x-t3 works

Comment: Does not seem to work on the X-H1 unless there's another setting that is important that maybe you have set on your camera but I don't on mine.

Comment: @user3833000 Are you turning off face/eye AF *in video mode*?  I think you need to have a function button mapped to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Turn OFF face detection and AF-S will work.